# How do I remove a to do list item after it is added

Tags: javascript

I really tried everything, almost every function in JS. But I cannot remove the list item from the to-do list once it is added. I have tried adding event listeners, onclick=" " etc but nothing works. Can someone please look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank You, any help is much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>To-Do-List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>My To Do List</h1>
    </div>
        <form autocomplete="off">
       <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="Title...">
   </form>
       <button id="addTask">Add</button>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <div id="tasks">
        <ul id="myUL">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
 <script>

var list = document.getElementById('myUL');
list.addEventListener("click", boxChecked);
function boxChecked(event){
    const element = event.target;
    if(element.type === "close"){
      delete element;
    }
}

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){




document.getElementById('addTask').addEventListener("click", function(){
var task = document.getElementById('task').value;

if(task == ""){
    alert("You Must Enter A Value!");
}else{
document.getElementById('myUL').innerHTML += '<li>' + task + '</li>' + '<button class="close" >&#10007</button>' + '<br><br>' + '<button class="check" >&#10003;</button>' + '<br><br>';
}

var button = document.querySelectorAll('.close');
for(var i = 0; i < button.length;i++){
button[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
this.parentNode.removeChild(this.previousSibling);
this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
});
}

var check = document.querySelectorAll('.check');
for(var i = 0; i < check.length;i++){
check[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
this.parentNode.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
});
}

 });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to concatenate `innerHTML` strings when you have listeners attached to elements inside, else the listeners will be lost. Instead, append elements properly with `appendChild`.

`delete element` won't actually do anything, because `element` is a variable, not a property of an object - try using `.remove()` instead, to remove the `li` (and put the button inside the `li` so that the HTML is valid).

```js
var list = document.getElementById('myUL');
list.addEventListener("click", boxChecked);

function boxChecked(event) {
  const element = event.target;
  if (element.className === "close") {
    element.parentElement.remove();
  }
}

document.getElementById('addTask').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var task = document.getElementById('task').value;

  if (task === "") return alert("You Must Enter A Value!");
  const li = list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
  li.textContent = task;
  const button = li.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
  button.className = 'close';
  button.textContent = '✗';
});
```

```css
.close {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>My To Do List</h1>
  </div>
  <form autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="Title...">
  </form>
  <button id="addTask">Add</button>
</div>

<br><br>

<div id="tasks">
  <ul id="myUL">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** simply needs to target `.close` rather than `close`. In addition to this, you'll probably want to target the close button's parent (the item itself), with `.parentNode`. Note that you probably don't want to hide it, but rather actually simply **remove** both the `<li>` and the close icon, so that you can add more items after removal of the item(s). This can be done with:

```
this.parentNode.removeChild(this.previousSibling);
this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
```

And can be seen working in the following:

```js
var list = document.getElementById('myUL');
list.addEventListener("click", boxChecked);

function boxChecked(event) {
  const element = event.target;
  if (element.type === "close") {
    delete element;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById('addTask').addEventListener("click", function() {
    var task = document.getElementById('task').value;

    if (task == "") {
      alert("You Must Enter A Value!");
    } else {
      document.getElementById('myUL').innerHTML += '<li>' + task + '</li>' + '<button class="close" >&#10007</button>' + '<br><br>';
    }

    var button = document.querySelectorAll('.close');
    for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
      button[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this.previousSibling);
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
      });
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>To-Do-List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>My To Do List</h1>
    </div>
    <form autocomplete="off">
      <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="Title...">
    </form>
    <button id="addTask">Add</button>
  </div>

  <br><br>

  <div id="tasks">
    <ul id="myUL">

    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also note that your stylesheet is missing a closing `"`, and you have two additional closing `</div>` that don't match anything in your above code.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. Just one more quick question, if i  want to remove the "tick box" or checkbox that I recently added, how would I do it

Comment: The code you've supplied doesn't have a checkbox in it, unless you're talking about the `.close` button? My code already removes that, but if you want to **only** remove that, the only line you'll need is `this.parentNode.removeChild(this);` (you won't need `this.parentNode.removeChild(this.previousSibling);`).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I will update my code in a sec. I now have a "checkbox"

Comment: Please help me @ObsidianAge